# Is there possibility to get Nunit "Property" attribute value if "Property" attribute is set for TestFixture level

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

Here is a TestFixture class that I have:

```
namespace TestApplication.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Property("type","smoke")]
    public class LoginFixture
    {
        [Test]
        [Property("role","user")]
        public void can_login_with_valid_credentials() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I set Nunit "Property" Attribute for Test and TestFixture levels.

It is easy to get "Property" value from Test level:

```
var test = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["role"]
```

But don't understand how to get "Property" value from TestFixture level. This doesn't work

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["type"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep track of the TestFixture context separately, which can be done using a `[TestFixtureSetup]` method:

```
[TestFixture]
[Property("type", "smoke")]
public class ContextText
{
    private TestContext _fixtureContext;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetup()
    {
        _fixtureContext = TestContext.CurrentContext;
    }

    [TestCase]
    public void TestFixtureContextTest()
    {
        // This succeeds
        Assert.That(_fixtureContext.Test.Properties["type"], Is.EqualTo("smoke"));
    }

    [TestCase]
    public void TestCaseContextTest()
    {
        // This fails
        Assert.That(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["type"], Is.EqualTo("smoke"));
    }
}
```

The above example is similar to unit tests contained in the NUnit 2.6.3 source code. For the actual NUnit unit tests, see TestContextTests.cs in the [downloadable source code](http://nunit.org/?p=download).