# NUnit Test Properties no longer supports Add?

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

In previous versions of nunit.framework (e.g. 3.7.1.0), you could add properties to `TestContext.Test`  Like this in C#:

`TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Add("NewProperty", "some value");`

I updated to a newer version (e.g. 3.10.1), and that is no longer an option?

I used to pack it with extra information about the test run during runtime. And then when my base class [TearDown] method ran, I would do extra processing for those properties.

Has that moved and/or is there another way to do that?

Comment: They have moved/changed this, it was always considered internal features so they didn't see the need to support this going forward, if I understood it correctly. There are much better alternatives like fields or method parameters for these kinds of things so you probably don't need to use them, though I do understand it will be some work to change your code.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen thanks for the insight.  I thought that this way was the best alternative.  Do you have an example or thought on what a better alternative would be?  I have a base class in a separate project, inherited by multiple classes in other projects for different solutions.  So create a method on the base class to call with parameters for things I need to pass down?  Or what is better?  I hate that it was taken away when people could have great uses for it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer from 2020.
It is still possible to set test property but using `Property` attribute: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Property-Attribute
The property value is still accessible via `TestContext`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25730287/4185987) example for more details